# Porting Java to Ruby - How to handle method signature overloading

Tags: java, ruby, overloading, optional-parameters

I'm having some fun porting some java code to ruby and I'm seeking guidance on how best to implement the method signature overloading of the below?

Using Ruby's optional parameters I can accommodate all of the overloads but this will lead to less than desirable 'conditional' coding to determine which parameters I'm dealing with. What is a more 'Ruby like' way to handle this?

```
  # public void set (ISOComponent c)
  # public void set(int fldno, String value)
  # public void set (String fpath, String value)
  # public void set (String fpath, ISOComponent c)
  # public void set (String fpath, byte[] value)
  # public void set (int fldno, byte[] value)
  def set(iso_component: nil, field_number: -1, string_value: '', file_path: '', byte_array: nil)
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no method signature overloading in ruby. The only sane alternative to what you have come up with that I can think of is to have separate methods for each signature: `set_iso_component`, `set_field_number_and_string_value`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For Ruby I think your best bet would be to rely on different OOP design principles, like duck typing. Instead of trying to create a `set` method that does 6 different things depending on which arguments you pass into it, your code would likely end up cleaner and more maintainable if you create objects that share a consistent interface that can be passed in as arguments to your `set` method. Here is an example:

```
class MyObject
  def set(obj)
    # depend on the interface: duck typing
    obj.set_the_things
  end
end

class ISOComponent
  def set_the_things
    # do ISOComponent specific stuff here
  end
end

class OtherInput
  attr_accessor :field_number, :value

  def set_the_things
    # do OtherInput specific stuff here
    # using @field_number and @value
  end
end

my_obj = MyObject.new
iso_component = ISOComponent.new
other_input = OtherInput.new

my_obj.set(iso_component)
my_obj.set(other_input)
```

Since `MyObject#set` only depends on the `set_the_things` methods from the objects that can be passed into it, you could pass in any number of different objects to this method so long as they implement their own `set_the_things` method that perform actions specific to their purpose. So if you need an input that handles a file path and ISO component, you would build an object that has a `set_the_things` method that does what it needs with the file path and ISO component, instead of trying to make your `set` method be everything to everyone (which is arguably more confusing for testing and for clients needing to understand what the `set` method does).

The article "[Duck Typing](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/duck_typing.html)" describes this.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading methods is not possible in Ruby, you need to either refactor the API or you could do some fancy meta-programming and evaluate types and invoke different method definitions (which you define with a DSL-like method) however this is definitely not the *standard* way of doing this I think.

Generally if you have a difficult method you might want to pass the arguments as a hash, and define default values for the fields. If you have multiple classes that should be evaluated to one target type you can define a method which converts all that types to your desired target type.

Ok I think I'm better at expressing myself using code:

```
def set(options = {})
  options[:str] = (options[:str] || "").to_s
  options[:num] = (options[:num] || 0).to_i
end
```

Here you'd use the `to_i` or the `to_s` method which is defined on almost anything, but you can define your own "converter" method to convert to a class which you want and then you needn't bother in your method about the type of a variable.

Also one cool thing is that in ruby parantheses are optional and you could invoke the earlier method without the curly braces.

```
 # These two are equivalent to eachother
 set({str: "Hello World", num: 123})
 set(str: "Hello World", num: 123)
```